# What is a word for extreme type of criticism?

Tags: single-word-requests

The type of criticism that is intended to destroy a person's reputation and self-esteem. A kind of criticism where a person's name is dragged through the mud. Is there a specific word(s) for it?

Comment: [An **excoriation** is a harsh criticism.](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/excoriation) But there are any number of related terms. Your example "victim" might be experiencing [character assassination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_assassination), for example,

Comment: If you're trying to destroy someone's reputation by dragging their name through the mud, that's typically termed ***character assassination***.

Comment: _Mud-slinging_ (also solid) is actually used, at least in the UK {[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mudslinging)}

Comment: where the criticism is untrue, it can be "slander"

Comment: I think the word you are looking for might be **pillorying**. This does not strictly mean criticism, but I do not think you are describing true criticism, but deliberate exposure to public ridicule and abuse - that is **pillorying**.

Answer (score 2):

### Candidates

The most common term for an attempt to destroy someone's reputation in a deliberate, conspicuous, focused and relentless way, by means of publically dragging their name through the mud is ***character assassination***.

From WordNet:

> #### Character Assassination
>
> *noun*
>   1. an attack intended to ruin someone's reputation

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=character%20assassination), likely sourcing WordNet, also gives the synonym ***blackwash*** (the opposite of *whitewash*).

AHD puts greater emphasis on the *malicious* nature of character [assassination](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=character%20assassination), as well as pointing out its common targets are public figures (politicians, celebrities, and other people in the public eye):

> The **malicious** denunciation or slandering of another person, especially as part of an effort to ruin the reputation of a public figure.

A related term, as [@Edwin Ashworth points out in the comments](http://the%20use%20of%20insults%20and%20accusations,%20especially%20unjust%20ones,%20with%20the%20aim%20of%20damaging%20the%20reputation%20of%20an%20opponent.), is ***mudslinging***. Here from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mudslinging):

> #### Mudslinging
>
> the use of insults and accusations, especially unjust ones, with the aim of damaging the reputation of an opponent.

Note the focus on "opponent": while both *character assassination* and *mudslinging* typically have public figures as their *targets*, *mudslinging* is usually reserved for scenarios where the attacker is a public figure as well (typically in an election or other contest between political opponents).

Again from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/muckraking):
A similar term is ***muck-raking***:

> #### Muck-raking
>
> *noun*
>   the action of searching out and publicizing scandalous information about famous people in an underhanded way.

Note the difference from *mud-slinging* here: both occur in similar contexts, though *mud-slinging* is typically reserved for political battles, *muck-raking* can also apply to tabloids and other gossip mongering, but *muck-raking* usually involves exposing *facts* which are damaging to the target. The metaphor is similar to "digging up dirt".

### Limitations

Which brings us to an important caveat with both *mud-slinging* and *character assassination*: **both typically connote *slander***, that is, part of the negative material being flogged is ***fabricated***, or at least potentially so.

That is, the attacker is less concerned with the *veracity* of his defamations than on whether they're *effective*.  So it's hard to use *character assassination* or *mud-slinging* if you want to communicate that while the attack is malicious, it is not necessarily *untrue*.

If that doesn't suit your need, you may consider other words for extreme or severe criticism, such as the ***excoriation*** that [FumbleFingers offered in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426441/what-is-a-word-for-extreme-type-of-criticism#comment1021986_426441).

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/excoriation):

> #### Excoriation
>
> An excoriation is a **harsh criticism**. If your senior prank involves releasing a flock of chickens into the halls of your high school, you're practically asking for an excoriation from the principal.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had a soft spot in my heart for Excoriate. It seems efficient and effective.

My only contribution is "Withering criticism." This describes the effect on the victim as a plant dying under the assault.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your answer. Please consider adding references to support the words you're suggesting.